# When is it possible to travel to the Americas?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

I'm currently running Stainless Steel 6.4.

My Carracks are on the westernmost side of the map and the year is 1384, yet I can't seem to travel to the Americas. Do I have to wait for a specific event to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to have the *World Is Round* event pop-up. In vanilla games it tends to appear at around 160-164 turns. You'll also notice that as soon as you start sailing west the map will cover a bigger area. After that you can just keep sailing to either Brazil (west from Lisbon), Mexico (West from London) or Florida (Northwestern most part of the map)